# Jquery - Insert value into h5 dynamically from div text

Tags: jquery, html

Get text value from div and insert into  tag via jquery. getting Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: error.

Hardcoded value to  works fine.

**JS:**

```
$('.select-destination').on('click', function () {
 let getDiscovery = $('.findTxt').text();
 //it works fine $('<h5>Find other DISCOVERY hotels</h5>').insertBefore($('.group-result.gha-group:first'));
 $("'<h5>'+getDiscovery+'</h5>'").insertBefore($('.group-result:first'));
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="findTxt hidden">Find other Hotels</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typo or mistake here - should be:

```
$('<h5>'+getDiscovery+'</h5>').insertBefore($('.group-result:first'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.select-destination').on('click', function() {
  let getDiscovery = $('.findTxt').text();
  $("<h5>" + getDiscovery + "</h5>").insertBefore($('.group-result:first'));
});
```

```html
<button class="select-destination">Click</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="findTxt hidden">Find other Hotels</div>
<h5 class="group-result"></h5>
<h5 class="group-result"></h5>
<h5 class="group-result"></h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is syntax mistake with the quotes in the below statement

```
 $("'<h5>'+getDiscovery+'</h5>'").insertBefore($('.group-result:first'));
```

i have corrected the syntax error in quotes .Please refer this code to overcome this issue.

```js
$('.select-destination').on('click', function() {
  let getDiscovery = $('.findTxt').text();
  $("<h5>" + getDiscovery + "</h5>").insertBefore($('.group-result:first'));
});
```

```html
<button class="select-destination">Click</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="findTxt hidden">Find other Hotels</div>
<h5 class="group-result"></h5>
```